# IAM / AWS Access control via Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, entra-id

I am trying to figure out how to configure IAM in Amazon AWS to use Windows Azure Active Directory.

I found http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx71TWXXJ3UI14/Enabling-Federation-to-AWS-using-Windows-Active-Directory-ADFS-and-SAML-2-0, however it is about configuring ADFS.

WAAD supports SAML 2.0 http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-identity/

Has anyone figured it out yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Active Directory exposes SAML 2.0 endpoints metadata.  The meta documentation can be found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195592.aspx.

The meta data can be obtained via:

https://login.windows.net/YourTenantDomainName/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Download the xml file, remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` from the top of the document and import the file using AWS console, in the Create Identity Provider action in AWS Console.

Answer (score 2):

Haroon is correct about the location for download the XML metadata.

You must re-save the document without a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) before Amazon will accept it. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=564190&#564190